# Is it haram for muslims with disabilities to have children?

Tags: halal-haram, parents, children, disability

my name is Alessandro and I'm a 25 year old boy, I've been a muslim for about a year. I have a doubt that I'm not sure I'll find the answer in the Holy Scriptures.
I think it's a difficult question, I haven't found any answers on the internet.

I have severe deafness and it gets worse every year as does my nearsightedness. And not only that, i can get sick easily but that doesn't stop me from working hard.

I can work hard to support my family, so i would like to get married and have children.
My question is, can i have children? I may be able to raise them with the help of my wife and family. But I fear to anger Allah and fall from His Grace.

I think that's a legitimate question to ask, because people have always looked down on people with disabilities. And so often families are ashamed to have children with problems because they are regarded as a disgrace from God. I hope to get an answer...

Comment: It is not haram. Just do your best and everything in a halal manner. Also, may Allah cure your from your illnesses, Ameen.

Answer (score 1):

It is never haram to have children. Rather it is categorically recommended to have them:

> فالآن باشروهن وابتغوا ما كتب الله لكم
>
> So now, have relations with them and seek that which Allah has decreed for you [i.e., offspring].
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:187](https://quran.com/2/187?translations=20)</sup>

> ‏ تزوجوا الولود الودود فإني مكاثر بكم
>
> Marry the one who is fertile and loving, for I will boast of your great numbers.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2050) and [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:3227)</sup>

Fear of not being able to raise children because of a lack of means is misplaced:

> ولا تقتلوا أولادكم خشية إملاق نحن نرزقهم وإياكم
>
> And do not kill your children for fear of poverty. We provide for them and for you.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 17:31](https://quran.com/17/31?translations=20)</sup>

Fear of having disabled children is not a reason which makes reproduction haram. Whether or not the child inherits the disability is Allah's will - He can grant a disabled child to healthy parents, and He can grant a healthy child to disabled parents. Also whether or not you actually manage to have a child or are able avoid its birth via contraception is Allah's will.

> ما من نسمة كائنة إلى يوم القيامة إلا هي كائنة
>
> There is no soul that is destined to exist but will come into existence, till the Day of Resurrection.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5210)</sup>

Also see: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/267083/